# How to validate Network connection in c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have an event connectEvent , which is not triggering at the time when clients Network connection to the server lost, but it will trigger at the time when new client establish connection after first ones disconnection ,that means after triggering ConnectEvent. I am not sure what the reason behind

So here my question is how i can trigger 'DisconnectEvent' once the network down,  i am not getting any idea
What i beleive is if (Connectivity = false) we can call DisconnectEvent, but where and how we can use that one ,, shall we use in Initialize() method

Comment: or Do i need to create code based on System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() for checking network connection